# How to pass Javascript Object to PHP with Ajax in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

How can I pass a Javascript Object to PHP with Ajax in Wordpress?

The code below returns 0, instead of the object. What is missing so that I can use the amount value in the PHP file?

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

   var whatever = {
     amount: 1234,
   };
   whatever = JSON.stringify(whatever);
  var data = {
    action: "my_action",
    whatever: whatever,
  };

  // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
  jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
    alert("Got this from the server: " + response);
  });
});
```

PHP

```
function my_action()
{
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval($_POST['whatever']);
    $whatever = json_decode($whatever);

    // $whatever += 10;

    echo $whatever;

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

Comment: You are trying to turn the `whatever` value `{ amount: 1234 }` into a integer by doing `$whatever = intval($_POST['whatever']);`. you should use `$whatever = json_decode($_POST['whatever']);` first then grab the value of `$whatever["amount"]` and use `$whatever = intval($whatever["amount"])` to turn it into a integer

Comment: Thanks. I actually do not need the `intval()`, I want to have access to the object in PHP. Though, with your suggestion it returns `NULL`.

Comment: If i echo $whatever before json_decode() it returns the string `{\"amount\":1234}`. After json_decode() it becomes `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue on your PHP, try this:

```
function my_action()
{
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = $_POST['whatever'];
    $whatever = json_decode($whatever);
    $amount = intval($whatever['amount']); 

    echo $amount;

    wp_die(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually do not need the `intval()`, I want to have access to the object in PHP. Though, with your suggestion it returns `NULL`.

Comment: If i echo $whatever before json_decode() it returns the string `{\"amount\":1234}`. After json_decode() it becomes `null`.